# marketing cloud soql filter by row number

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I've a DE which has 2M records and would like to split it to 1.1M and 0.9M using SQL query. A query like below throws error. Any thoughts?

```
select 
A, B, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _CustomObjectKey) as rowNum
from 
[TEST_TABLE]
where
rowNum < 1100000


select 
A, B, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY _CustomObjectKey) as rowNum
from 
[TEST_TABLE]
where
rowNum >= 1100000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, You need to split this into two seperate SQL Queries. Afterwords, you have multiple ways to split your data.

Not knowing the attributes of your data extensions, this would be a generic solution to what you're trying to do :

**1st Query :** *(Let's say this goes into a Data Extension named [Target_DE_1] for the 0.9M records)*

```
Select Top 45 Percent
A, B, C
from 
[TEST_TABLE]
Order by [SomeKindOfAttribute] desc/asc
```

**2nd Query :** *Where your 1.1M records will go*

```
Select 
A, B, C
from [TEST_TABLE] As A
Left Join [Target_DE_1] As B On A.Key = B.Key
Where B.Key Is Null
```

(*) SomeKindOfAttribute would be an orderable attribute in your DE

(**) Key being a unique ID in your DE

Answer (score 0):

Why use row numbers on _customobjectkey, when it already increments by one for each row? I’d suggest finding the min and max values for _customobjectkey and using that in your WHERE.